# React Router 4 and exact path with dynamic param

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have issues with component being displayed on every single path because React Router 4 isn't using exact for that route (or so it appears).

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Explore} />
<Route path="/about" component={About} />

// The one making problems
<Route
    path="/:username"
    exact={true}
    render={props => <Profile {...props} />}
/>
```

So when I go to http://example.com/about, my Profile component is still being rendered. I guess the problem is in the route as it expects param `:username` and that goes right after `/` (root). Am I doing something wrong? I could add another route for `/:username`, like `/profile/:username`, but I'd like to keep it the way it is, if it's possible.

Comment: Are these 3 in the same `Switch` statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you are not using Switch.
Switch will solve your problem because it will only render the first path that matches.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  <Route path="/:username" render={props => <Profile {...props} />} />
  <Route path="/" component={Explore} />
  <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
</Switch>
```