# What is wrong with the React components Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

Attempting to build a flashcard app with React and React Hooks, I am able to get my home screen rendered. When introducing Router, I am able to click the link, update the path to be the one I am looking for, but nothing is being rendered from that new page.

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";
import ShowAllDecks from './ShowAllDecks';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function Layout() {
  const [flashcards, setFlashcards] = useState([])

  //Delete a deck of flashcards
  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    const result = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?'); 
    if (result) {
      setFlashcards(flashcards.filter(deck => deck.id !== id));
    };
 };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get('http://localhost:5000/decks?_embed=cards')
    .then(res => {
      setFlashcards(res.data.map((questionItem, index) => {

        return {
          id: `${index}-${Date.now()}`,
          name: questionItem.name,
          description: questionItem.description,
          cards: questionItem.cards.length,
        }
      }))
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path={'/'}>
            <ShowAllDecks flashcards={flashcards} setFlashcards={setFlashcards} deleteHandler={deleteHandler} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <NotFound />
    </div>
  )

}
```

ShowAllDecks.js --> List of flashcard decks

```
import React from 'react';
import Deck from './Deck';
import ViewDeck from './ViewDeck';

function ShowAllDecks({ flashcards, deleteHandler }) {

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <button>Create New</button>
            {flashcards.map((flashcard) => {
                return (
                    <Deck flashcards={flashcards} flashcard={flashcard} key={flashcard.id} deleteHandler={deleteHandler} />
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShowAllDecks;
```

Deck.js --> Individual deck of flashcards

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ViewDeck from './ViewDeck';

function Deck({ flashcard, flashcards, setFlashcards, deleteHandler}) {

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='card'>
            <div className='card-body'>
                <h3 className='card-title'>{flashcard.name}</h3>
                <p className='card-text'>{flashcard.description}</p>
                <p className='card-text'>{flashcard.cards} cards</p>
                <Link to={`decks/${flashcard.id}`}>View</Link>
                <button>Study</button>
                <button onClick={() => deleteHandler(flashcard.id)}><i className="fas fa-trash" /></button>
            </div>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact={true} path={`decks/${flashcard.id}`}>
                        <ViewDeck flashcards={flashcards} flashcard={flashcard} deleteHandler={deleteHandler} />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Deck;
```

ViewDeck.js --> Should be a new screen for individual flashcard deck where I can view the list of cards in the deck, edit the cards, or add new cards.

```
import React from 'react';

function ViewDeck({ flashcards, flashcard, deleteHandler }) {
    console.log(flashcards)
    return (
        <p>{flashcards.name}</p>
    )
}
 
export default ViewDeck;
```

When on the index route, flashcards is an array of objects and flashcard is a deck of cards object. What am I doing wrong with my Routes or components that make my component not render?

Example of the URL:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Rendering in React",
    "description": "React's component structure allows for quickly building a complex web application that relies on DOM manipulation. ",
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "front": "Differentiate between Real DOM and Virtual DOM.",
        "back": "Virtual DOM updates are faster but do not directly update the HTML",
        "deckId": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "front": "How do you modify the state of a different React component?",
        "back": "Not at all! State is visible to the component only.",
        "deckId": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "front": "How do you pass data 'down' to a React child component?",
        "back": "As properties or props",
        "deckId": 1
      },
      {
        "cards": [],
        "front": "b",
        "back": "b",
        "deckId": 1,
        "id": 7
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: All the routing happens in App.js. That page is basically just deciding what  sections to show based on the url. So move your Route from Deck.js into the switch in App.js. So App.js will have TWO routes in the switch. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Will I think that makes sense. I went ahead and adjusted App.js so it has both routes. I took the route out of Deck.js. I left the <Link> there so it knows where to go. But I am still going to the same screen with nothing rendered. Not even a console log. I'm not sure what would cause that

Comment: If you can load your app into a Sandbox, we can show you exactly where to put stuff.

Comment: It's probably the `exact` prop. I can't remember exactly but this answer says you don't need it in the switch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986386/react-router-4-and-exact-path-with-dynamic-param

Comment: @codemonkey https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-smoke-lrk3m?file=/public/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in your Sandbox you left the `Deck` element empty, I had to come up with my own:

```
          <div>
            Card Name: {flashcard.name}
            <br />
            <Link to={`/decks/${flashcard.id}`}>click on card</Link>
          </div>
```

But the idea is simple, you need to define your Routes at the higher level and then just create links to the routes inside your `Deck` element. Here is how your route definitions should look:

```
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path={"/"}>
            <ShowAllDecks
              flashcards={flashcards}
              setFlashcards={setFlashcards}
              deleteHandler={deleteHandler}
            />
          </Route>
        </Switch>

        {flashcards.map((item, i) => (
          <Switch key={i}>
            <Route exact path={`/decks/${item.id}`}>
              <ViewDeck flashcard={item} deleteHandler={deleteHandler} />
              {/* <div>Some stuff here</div> */}
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        ))}
      </Router>
```

Here is a working [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sammet-2bpc0?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: This is really appreciated. I didn't even think to map through the flashcards in App.js. But that makes sense in order to properly route the pages. I learned a lot, thank you so much!